# In a multithreaded process on a system with multiple (physical) CPUs, how is thread scheduling handled?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, parallel-processing, linux-kernel

Kind of a broad question, but I'm curious about the details of thread scheduling in a single process application on a machine with multiple physical CPUs.

EDIT - wanted to clarify that below im talking about phyiscal CPUs. I've got a pretty good handle on how a process/threads work with a multicore CPU, but I'm talking multiple physical CPU dyes on the motherboard (like 2 4-core Xeons).

ANSWER - thanks to the responses from brokenfoot and nosid, I think I've got it:
 - Linux scheduler has different NUMA policies that affect thread scheduling in regards to their memory mutation/access patterns in regards to core/dye.
 - Cache coherency across dyes is possible, but slower as expected.
 - Best course of action- control mutability of shared memory (try to be immutable)
 - Use an internal (in-process) task scheduler that respects locality of threads
 - Use a NUMA policy that works with your in-process task scheduler

Assumptions:

- Cache coherency is the magic that allows multiple cores to operate on shared memory. (confirmed)
- As far as I know, cache coherency is possible over multiple CPUs, but at reduced performance (Linux 3+, system has multiple modern multi-core Xeons CPUs). (confirmed)

So the situation:

- I have a multi-threaded single process service that does... stuff, in parallel. It can effectively utilize multiple cores and divides work up in a way that generally avoids cpu-core cache misses and coherency abuse. Executor has relative thread-affinity for tasks.
- The service threads can utilize shared data (mostly immutable) in the process.
- The service architecture is done in a way that running multiple processes on the same box is possible, but is advantageous to have only 1 process per box (shared cache, resources, etc).

The questions:

- Is cache coherency possible between multiple CPUs? Is it practical? (It is, at reduced performance)
- How will linux schedule the threads between CPUs? (If possible)
- Is there some way to pin a process to a single CPU? (confirmed)
- And ultimately... do I do one process per CPU and pin? Or 1 per box (which would be cool, if i dont screw myself with slow cross-CPU cache misses) (starting to sound like 1 process is good, as long as my parallel tasks have affinity to a certain thread and mostly immutable data)

Comment: There are **directory** based cahce coherency protocol for coherency between large no of processors in a NUMA machine. Google it up.  And Kernel threads under Linux are implemented as processes that share resources. The scheduler does not differentiate between a thread and a process

Comment: yes, im aware of that. pthreads are presented to the kernel as processes essential (their own PID and such). This is a more a question of how that resource sharing works with multiple multi-core units (cache coherency of shared memory between multiple physical CPUs)

Comment: @brokenfoot i guess as a followup, does NUMA work across multiple dyes? or is it just for cache coherence local to the dye? and if does, is cache coherence notably slower between multiple dyes vs multiple local cores?

Comment: Yes, it does work across multiple dyes. And as you pointed out, it is slower in comparison to the cache coherency local to the multicore dye. It is called ccNUMA where communication between the cache controller is using IPCs. Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access#Cache_coherent_NUMA_.28ccNUMA.29

Comment: @brokenfoot thanks tons! So this confirms my suspicion regarding cache coherency.... now I'm just wondering if linux schedules this different. is there any sort of implicit affinity to one dye for threads of a process?

Answer (score 5):

> Is cache coherency possible between multiple CPUs? Is it practical?

It's up to the programming language, compiler and runtime environment. They take care, that your program can use several CPUs and still have consistent memory operations. For that purpose, the programming language typically define a so-called *memory model*.

> How will linux schedule the threads between CPUs? (If possible)

Without going into details, it typically uses all CPU cores. There is no static assignment between threads and cores. That means, a thread can be running for a while on one core, and later on another core. However, the Linux kernel tries to keep threads local to their memory, because systems with several CPU sockets have a non-uniform memory architecture (NUMA).

> Is there some way to pin a process to a single CPU?

Yes, look for *cpuset*.

> And ultimately... do I do one process per CPU and pin? Or 1 per box (which would be cool, if i dont screw myself with slow cross-CPU cache misses)

If your application benefits from using shared memory, use one process per box. There is no disadvantage performance-wise.

Comment: thanks for the response! I think i failed to clarify above though: I'm wondering how the process will behave on a system with multiple physical CPUs (each of which is multi-core)

Comment: so the ultimate question is really... do I use one process per physical CPU (regardless of cores per dye), or one per box?

Comment: @ColinGodsey: From a functional point of view, there is no difference between multi-core and multi-socket. Of course, there is a difference in performance, when accessing memory attached to another socket. However, in most situations that's not the bottleneck. Usually the bottleneck is memory shared between threads, where at least one thread performs write operations. These operations are expensive regardless whether the threads are running on different cores or different sockets.

Comment: thanks! so as long as I keep my data relatively immutable, should be good? also, do you know this affects the linux scheduler? will it naturally try to keep threads of one process local to one dye (as much as possible)?

Comment: It's getting better. See for example [NUMA scheduling progress](http://lwn.net/Articles/568870/) and http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b795854b1fa70f6aee923ae5df74ff7afeaddcaa

Comment: I'm sorry for necroing the thread, but I always thought that cache coherency is a feature of your hardware architecture, specifically of the cache controllers using a [multitude of possible protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherency_protocols_(examples)). I don't think that cache coherency depends on the *language*. Cache coherency has been implemented in pretty much any multi-cpu architecture since the days of SMP (more than one chip on the MB, one core per chip).